# Follow image contour using marching square in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am new to Python and would be grateful if anyone can point me the right direction or better still some examples.

I am trying to write a program to convert image (jpeg or any image file) into gcode or x/y coordinate. Instead of scanning x and y direction, I need to follow the contour of objects in the image. For example, a doughnut with outer circle and inner circle, or a face with face outline and inner contour of organs.

I know there is something called marching square, but not sure how to do it in python?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an implementation of marching squares in scikit-image: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at OpenCV's [findContours function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) which perform the same operation very fast. It is not pure python but there is a very nice Python binding making use of numpy arrays, etc ... (the new "cv2" module).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following procedure:

1) Convert your image to a binary image (nxn numpy array): 1(object pixels) and 0 (background pixels)

3) Since you want to follow a contour, you can see this problem as: finding the all the object pixels belonging to the same object. This can be solved by the Connected Components Labeling Object.

4) Once you have your objects identified, you can run the Marching squares algorithm over each object. MS consist in divide your image in n squares and then evaluating the value of all the vertex for a given square. MS will find the the border by analyzing each square and finding those in which the value of at least one of the vertex of a given square is 0 whereas the other vertex of such square are 1 --> The border/contour is contained in such square.